# why am i getting syntax errors using csv

Tags: python

I have made a program for a holiday csv file but it keeps coming up as an invalid syntax.

```
def summer_template:
        summer_template == 1:
    open("holiday.csv","w")
    summer_list["shorts","sandels","shirt(s)","suncream"]
    summer_extra=input("what do you want to do  on holiday")
    holiday_file=csv.writer(summer_list,summer_extra)
    csvfile.close()
```

the error is located where the "summer_template" is

Comment: summer_template == 1: "what is this exactly ?"

Answer (score 1):

It's python, you need to have indentation done correctly. Try to copy the whitespace from the "open" line and replace the whitespace on the offending line.

And it looks like there's an if statement missing. If that's the case everything under if needs to be further indented. Remember you can't mix tabs and spaces either.

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing an `if` statement? Using the `==` operator usually is done within an `if` statement.

https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/controlflow.html

Answer (score 0):

- function definitions should have parentheses: `def summer_template():`.
- Perhaps you mean `if summer_template == 1:`.  In that case, everything you want to be in that `if` block needs to be indented.